# RubyMine inline refactoring?

Tags: ruby, rubymine

Here is some long-form code:

```
  c.jobs.each do |j|
    j.products.each do |p|
      p.destroy
    end
    j.payments.each do |p|
      p.destroy
    end
    j.destroy
  end
```

RubyMine has an inline refactoring tool, but it's disabled when I try to refactor any part of this.

I would expect to be able to click on the do by products and inline refactor to:

```
j.products.each { |p| p.destroy }
```

In a single keystroke.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you're refactoring it to be smaller, why not `j.products.each(&:destroy)`? Also if this is Rails, don't forget about the `dependent: :destroy` option.

Comment: Convert `do` to `{}` is the refactor you want then, as per Alexey.

Answer (score 1):

That's not what inlining means.

Inlining means replacing a function invocation with the functionality of that function, e.g.,

```
def some_fun(x, y)
  x + y
end

z = some_fun(a, b) + c
# Becomes
z = a + b + c
```

Comment: Maybe meant "inoneline" refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to change the block form from `do ... end` to a curly-bracket one `{ ... }`. That's how you do it:

1. Put your cursor on a `do` that you want to change.
2. Type <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> and select `Convert do block to {}`
3. That's it!